# Open .btw file from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, bartender

I want to open a `.btw` format file.

This is my code.

```
Sub Printlabel() 
    Dim printdata As Workbook 
    Dim history As Workbook 

    Dim btApp As BarTender.Application 
    Dim btFormat As BarTender.Format 
    Dim btSubString As BarTender.SubString 

    Set btApp = New BarTender.Application 
    Set btFormat = btApp.Formats.Open("D:\test\test.btw") 
    btApp.Visible = False 
    btFormat.SetNamedSubStringValue "Part", Filename

    'Select the data source 
    btSubString = btFormat.NamedSubStrings.GetSubString(1) 

    'Show the data source's name 
    MessageBox.Show (btSubString.Name) 
End Sub
```

The error I got:

> Compile Error:
>   User-defined type not defined

Comment: Please add your code and error message as code/text in your original question ([edit] your question, no comment for code please) and format it as code block. Also please always include in which line the error occurs. • The error is probably because of a missing reference.

Comment: Can you please tell in which line you get the error?

Comment: i got error in this line `Dim btApp As BarTender.Application`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set a reference to the BarTender library.

Therefore goto **Tools › References** in the VBA Editor menu and browse for the BarTender Library.

[image]

For more information see: [Check or Add an Object Library Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/How-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference)